# Opening a Modal from a Modal in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to open a `Modal` from a `TouchHighlight` located in another modal. Basically what should happen is, the `TouchHighlight` in the parent main `Modal` should open another secondary `Modal` on top of it, without closing the main `Modal`.

But I get the following error.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <RCTModalHostViewController: 0x7fc408fb2460>  on <RCTWrapperViewController: 0x7fc40b2c1ac0> which is already presenting (null)
```

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Okay found the way. The secondary `Modal` code should be inside the Primary `Modal`. This fixes the problem.

```
<Modal
        animationType='fade'
        transparent={true}
        visible={this.state.modalVisibility}>

    <Modal
            animationType='fade'
            transparent={true}
            visible={this.state.secondaryModalVisibility}>

        <View style={[styles.modalContainer, modalBackgroundStyle]}>
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>

                {this.secondaryContent()}

            </View>
        </View>
    </Modal>

    <View style={[styles.modalContainer, modalBackgroundStyle]}>
        <View style={styles.innerContainer}>

            {this.mainContent()}

        </View>
    </View>
</Modal>
```

Comment: you're the saviour

Comment: it seems that showing modal over modal does not work on ios!

Comment: @EmadBayat, did you find a solution for that?

Comment: It works but it messes my react components structure up quite a bit. I myself hate this solution. If anyone has a better solution please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a callback on the button press to the parent screen to close the first modal and then open the second modal
I have done this with this method

Answer (score 1):

For iOS, we have to `setTimer()` to show the second modal. So we should dismiss the first modal, and then `setTimer()` for the second modal.

Comment: That's if the second modal doesn't reside inside the first.

Comment: Thank you @NimilaHiranya , I'll try modal inside modal. Because I still have this problem.

Comment: is `setTimer` some react-native function or do you mean `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in a project that as big it got, more Modals were be created on more and more screens and containers, so I created [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-nested-modals) for controlling all my modals dynamically all over the app